# Why is clearing a tbb::concurrent_unordered_map so much slower than clearing a std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, performance, concurrency, destructor, tbb

I have a `tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<size_t, std::vector<size_t>>` - or, alternatively, an `std::unordered_map<size_t, std::vector<size_t>>`.

Clearing the map, either by calling `.clear()` or when the destructor runs, takes significantly longer (at least 5 times as long by my measurements) in the TBB case. I don't see how any concurrency issues can be the cause of such a slowdown, since `.clear()` is specifically called out as "unsafe for concurrent use" in TBB documentation.

Why is clearing so much slower in the TBB case? (And is there anything I can do about it?)

Answer (score 0):

std::unordered_map is not thread-safe by default. The slowdown you are experiencing may be due to the overhead of maintaining the data required for concurrent access.

You can try using the parallel_for_each algorithm to iterate over the map and clear each element in parallel. In the final, you can use .clear() to clear the map.
This approach may be faster than calling .clear() directly on the concurrent_unordered_map.
Please refer to the Pro TBB Textbook for more information.

Have you checked with the latest Intel oneTBB 2021.9? And also you can use the tbb::concurrent_hash_map container which supports concurrent insertion, lookup, and erasure.